# Question word order in statements

Tags: word-order, reported-speech

Are following sentences correct?

1. She asked me **why I didn't** go to the doctor.
2. She got surprised **why didn't I** go the doctor.

If they are correct, is there any difference in meaning between them?

Comment: Subject-auxiliary inversion does not occur in an embedded clause.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. "Why I didn't go to the doctor" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). Subject-auxiliary Inversion doesn't normally occur in such clauses, so 1. is correct. 2. is incorrect since there is inversion of the subject "I" and the auxiliary verb "didn't".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is the good one.  You are making a statement, so you use the order for a statement instead of the order for asking a question.

Their meanings would be the same if the second version was grammatical:

"**She was surprised. Why didn't I go to the doctor?**"

Answer (score -2):

The first sentence is correct and the second is not correct. `She got surprised why I didn't go to the doctor.`. Difference? I do not know.